# Was the figure Aoba found supposed to be Madoka?

Tags: madoka-magica, gakuen-polizi

in *Gakuen Polizi* Chapter 3, Sasami Aoba comes across a girl who's looking through the trash, looking for something she lost which she can't buy again, similar to what happened to Aoba herself the day before, but rather than her badge, it's an anime figure phone strap.

[image: Chapter 3 - Page 69 bottom]

[image: Chapter 3 - Page 70 top]

Now, given that the girl's description says that the figure had pink hair and we see what the figure was, it looks very much like Madoka Kaname from *Puella Magi Madoka Magica* with the bows and style of dress

[image: Madoka Kaname Magical Girl form]

Was this figure supposed to be Madoka?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. Pink hair in bangs, dress similar to Madoka's. It is supposed to be Madoka. You can see example of Madoka keychain which serverd as an inspiration here[image]:

Or actual phone strap here: [image]

Comment: As close as the similarity goes, we prefer official statements that the mangaka did use Madoka as an inspiration. Otherwise, this is the same case with [this question regarding Violet and Saber](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/44430/is-violet-inspired-by-saber) (with 1 deleted answer without referencing official statement)

Comment: Got it now. Sorry about this, didn't know I have to get official statement. Sorry again.