# Why do Karen from Yu-Gi-Oh! and Akiza from Code Geass look alike?

Tags: code-geass, yu-gi-oh

Here is Karen from *Code Geass* and Akiza from *Yugioh*.

[image]

Why do these two have the exact same design? Is there any background story about the character designer?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who can't tell them apart.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing really beyond the similar appearance which which isn't a new thing as various series have done this, One Piece & Fairy Tail, Parasyte & Yuri!!! On Ice, Hunter X Hunter & One Punch Man ([Source](https://www.cbr.com/anime-characters-who-look-disturbingly-alike/#shanks-amp-gildarts-clive-one-piece-amp-fairy-tail))

neither the [Yu-Gi-Oh Wikia on Akiza](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Akiza_Izinski#Trivia) (Last Dot Point) or [The Code Geass Wikia on Kallen](https://codegeass.fandom.com/wiki/Kallen_K%C5%8Dzuki#Trivia) (7th Dot Point) says anything beyond how similar they are

Akiza's

> Akiza bears a striking resemblance to Kallen Kōzuki from Code Geass both sport a crimson theme as well as a similar hairstyle. Personality-wise they are not exact, but similar since they try to isolate themselves from the present society during the story and are hostile to the people they perceive as enemies. They also have possible romantic feelings for the main protagonists of their respective series.

Kallen's

> Aki Izayoi from Yu-Gi-Oh! 5D's bears a striking resemblance to Kallen; both sport a crimson theme as well as a similar hairstyle. Personality-wise they are not exact, but similar since they try to isolate themselves from the present society during the story and are hostile to the people they perceive as enemies. They also have romantic feelings for the main protagonists of their respective series.

If one was inspired by the other, it would be that Akiza was inspired from Kallen as

- *Code Geass* came out in 2006 by Sunrise

while

- *Yu-Gi-Oh 5D's* came out 2008 by Gallop

but without any further information, i'd say it's just coincidence

Comment: Thank you. Great analysis. I don't know why my question was so down voted.

Answer (score 1):

Because nothing under the sun is original, they're just unique in their own ways.

It was probably either a coincidence or an inspiration.

Comment: Hiya, while this is possibly the case, it might be better if the answer can be expanded with more info (example: like [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/67497/2516)). Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but I really can't think of any supporting info to expand my answer. That simple answer on my post is pretty much the only thing that I could think about right now. However, I do know for sure that nothing under the sun is original because those two characters are not the only ones that look similar. I've made over thousands of collages that show characters that look similar or almost identical to other lookalikes in anime, cartoons, and video games, and that's how I know for sure.